# overwriting data in a .txt file c++

Tags: c++

I have a functions overwrites data on an existing file, however it isn't working properly here is my code:

```
 void printList(entry* my_node)
 {  
        ofstream output;      
        output.open("output.txt");

        std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf

        if(my_node == NULL) return;
        else {
            string x=my_node->forename;
            output<<x<<endl; 
            output<<my_node->surname<<endl;
            output<<my_node->email<<endl;
            output<<my_node->number<<endl;
            std::cout<<"forename:  "<<my_node->forename<<std::endl; 
            std::cout<<"surname:  "<<my_node->surname<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"email:  "<<my_node->email<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Phone Number:  "<<my_node->number<<std::endl;

            printList(my_node->next);   
            output.close();
        }
}
```

when i do this it clears the file and don't write anything to it ...i have also tried to first clear the file and then write to it

```
output.clear();

output.close();

output.open("output.txt",ios ::out|ios::app);

std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();

//save old buf

///and then the rest but it didn't work as well
```

Any help please????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open and therefore overwrite the new file every time you reach `printList`, even in the case where `my_node` is null. If that is not your intention, then move

```
ofstream output;
output.open("output.txt");
```

into the body of the if statement. Or if you would like all nodes content in the same file, move it out of the traversal.

Also note that `ofstream`s contructor takes arguments, so you can write

```
ofstream output("output.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `printList` recursively with each next value until you reach the end of the list, which calls `printlist(NULL)`. Then the output file is truncated *again* for the last time. This is the reason why the file is empty.

To write the whole list to the file, use a loop and inside the loop write each element, e.g.

```
while (my_node != NULL) {
    output << my_node->forename << endl;
    output << my_node->surname << endl;
    output << my_node->email << endl;
    output << my_node->number << endl;
    /* ... */
    my_node = my_node->next;
}

output.close();
```